# Stability of the equilibrium point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I have to check the stability of the equilibrium point of the system 
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-x+\ln (|t|+1)y-\sin (t)z, \\ \frac{dy}{dt}=-\ln (|t|+1)x-y+e^tz, \\ \frac{dz}{dt}=\sin (t)x-e^ty-z$$

$$$$

The characteristic equation of the above system is $$\begin{vmatrix}
-1-\kappa & \ln (|t|+1) & -\sin (t)\\ 
\ln (|t|+1) & -1-\kappa & e^t\\ 
\sin (t) & -e^t & -1-\kappa
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

Do we have to find the eigenvalues and then would the stability depend on the sign of these eigenvalues?

Comment: Another suggestion, simpler: do you see how to find a Lyapunov function?

Comment: Not really... Could you give me a hint? @Jonas

Comment: What would be the best possible Lyapunov function?

Comment: When we take the function $v(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{2}$ the conditions to be a  lyapunov function are satisfied, rigjht? @Jonas

Comment: Right, that's it.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :-) @Jonas